# Angular.JS: click-to-edit directive form updates model, but http.post still uses "old" values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having a strange problem creating a click-to-edit directive with angular.js:

The model gets updated on form submit, but the updated model is not used in an following http.post, the old one is used.

For example, in a table: If I edit the "note" field of the first record from "secret" to "myNote", the bowsers console will show "myNote" as the value of the comment attribute of my item, but the server still recieves "secret".

To demonstrate this, I created a small example on github: https://github.com/madmarkus/angular.js-Sample
I will try to show only the relevant code here.

My Controller looks like

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('./items.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    }).error(
        function(){
            console.log("Failed to load items.");
        });

    $scope.saveEditor = function () {

        $scope.saveItem(this.item);
    };

    $scope.saveItem = function (w) {
        console.log("Attempt to safe: ");
        console.log(w);       
        $http.post("http://localhost:8888", w, {}).success(function () {
                console.log("post successfully sent");
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Error on save.");
        });

    };
}
```

and the app.js like

```
app = angular.module('planner', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/items', {templateUrl: 'item-list.html', controller: ListCtrl}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/items'});
    }]);

app.directive("clickToEdit", function() {
    var editorTemplate = '<div>' +
                            '<div ng-hide="view.editorEnabled" ng-click="enableEditor()" class="editable" ' +
                                'style="width: 100%; min-height: 1.5em; display:inline-block" >' +
                                '{{value}} ' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<form ng-show="view.editorEnabled">' +
                                '<input ng-model="view.editableValue"><br />' +
                                '<button class="btn" ng-click="save()" type="submit">Save</button>' +
                                ' or ' +
                                '<a ng-click="disableEditor()">cancel</a>.' +
                            '</form>' +
                        '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        template: editorTemplate,
        scope: {
            value: "=clickToEdit",
            saveCallback: "&saveFunction"
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.view = {
                editableValue: $scope.value,
                editorEnabled: false
            };

            $scope.enableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = true;
                $scope.view.editableValue = $scope.value;
            };

            $scope.disableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = false;
            };

            $scope.save = function() {
                $scope.value = $scope.view.editableValue;
                $scope.disableEditor();
                $scope.saveCallback();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Like mentined above, when I use the click&edit to change the note value of the first record from secret to myNote, the js debugger in the bowser and the console show the correct after-edit value:

```
[22:24:20.026] Attempt to safe: 
[22:24:20.026] ({id:"977", datetime:"21.07.2013 10:00", note:"myNote", remark:"important", comment:"editme", $$hashKey:"004"})
```

*But* the server receives still the "old" value:

```
Received body data:
{"id":"977","datetime":"21.07.2013 10:00","note":"secret","remark":"important","comment":"editme"}
```

From what I found&read, it might be a scoping issue i'm facing, but i just cant find the right way to handle it. Also played around with $scope.$apply()...

Any hints?

Any comments on the code are also very much appreciated ;-)

Thanks a lot

Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a timing problem. You need to be aware that chrome updates the message in console.log when the object you are printing changes.

When your directive calls the callback, it didn't updated the value you are binding yet. You can see this by adding breakpoints with chrome (put them on the console.log calls). A quick solution to this problem is to call the callback inside a $timeout, since it will cause another digest to be executed and then you know the value already was updated:

```
controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
    //...

    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.value = $scope.view.editableValue;
        $scope.disableEditor();
        $timeout(function() {
           $scope.saveCallback();
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply, using the code above, the function passed into timeout() seems to be never called, nor is the callback. DId i get something wrong?

Comment: Hi, I tested your code with this function and it worked. Have a look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0Ev8Ro?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot!  now it works :-) I missed the timeout as controller function parameter. sorry for that.

Comment: But that can't be "the" way to go, can it? Is there another way, without using $timeout, to accomplish updated values for callbacks?